# Python STDIN readline blocks

Tags: python

I have a script that writes to stdout like this:

```
# Send.py
import time

while(1):
    print "hello"
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Now I have another script that needs to read it as such:

```
# Listen.py
while(1) :

    print "reading.."
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    print data
```

---

```
python Send.py | python listen.py
```

Unfortunately, this just stops on reading and nothing is every printed. Why is that?

Comment: Probably due to flushing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print

Comment: Ah Fishsticks. I need to flush after every print, which is only a feature of python 3.3. Dammit!

Answer (score 3):

`read()` method will read until EOF, but the first program never end; `read()` will not return.

You need to read line by line.

Replace the following line:

```
data = sys.stdin.read()
```

with:

```
data = sys.stdin.readline()
```

In addition to that, `readline()` will return the read line with newline, and the `print` statement append new line after the string resulting empty lines inbetween. To prevent that, use `sys.stdout.write`:

```
data = sys.stdin.readline()
sys.stdout.write(data)
```

**UPDATE**

The shell will buffer output. To prevent it, flush the output:

```
import sys
import time

while 1:
    print "hello"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Alternatively, you can use `-u` option to make stdout, stderr unbuffered.

```
python -u send.py | python listen.py
```

Comment: Nope. I just tried. still doesnt work. 
import sys

# Listen.py
while(1) :

    print "reading.."
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
    print data

Comment: This is not working because `readline` is still blocking until it will receive a `\n` because the output is finished the `readline` will continue blocking for ever or until a `\n` appears (well, that will be never...).

Comment: @ovfstack, You may need to flush the output.

Comment: `readline` won't block forever, just `BLOCKSIZE / len("hello\n") * .1` seconds, or about 60 seconds.

Comment: @user3211152, `print` statement write the string with a newline (`\n`)

Comment: Also, the shell doesn't buffer the output. Python buffers its output.

Comment: @Robᵩ, I mean shell pipe buffer. Try `ulimit -p`. (-p     The pipe size in 512-byte blocks (this may not be set)
)

Answer (score -1):

This is because the program has not terminated yet and the `read()` is waiting for more io.
The pipe is like a blocking socket.

you may want to lookup python queues and make use of `get_nowait()`

Here is a answer that may help you:
[Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Try to look up blocking and non-blocking io in python too.